# CSS border transition

Tags: css

I'd like to create an input box and style it with border.
To do this I need to do `input:focus`, then I did it I don't know how to move on. 
If I want to change the background's transition then I do `transition: background Xs;` or `-webkit-transition: background Xs;`.

I've made a search and I didn't found anything that could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: So you want border , or background?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T93Du/1/  does this resemble your code in any way? Please, update it , with what you have and give us :P

Comment: I want border, @Drewness here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/h4ZKx/1/

Comment: @Holybreath this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current transition only applies to the element's `background`, *not* the `border`. Either change "background" to "border", remove "background" completely or add in "border" alongside your background:

```css
input {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    transition: background 0.2s, border 0.2s;
}

input:focus {
    border-color: tomato;
}
```

Comment: I meant to do this. ACCEPTED! THANKS!

Comment: Just to make sure, if I want to do it in milliseconds, instead of [border: 0.2s] I can do [border:200ms] ?

Comment: I believe it only accepts seconds. `0.2s` is 200ms.

Answer (score 1):

```
input:focus {
    border: 5px solid red;
    background: blue;
}
input {
    transition: border 1s, background 2s;
}
```

Remove what you don't need, border or background ;) You must specify transition in the element itself, and the desired effect in :focus.

Comment: Thanks for help! appreciate it.